# Task.WaitAll, how to find the tasks causing AggregateException

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Let's say that I got the following code:

```
var tasks = BuildTaskList();
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException exception)
{

}
```

How do I know which task threw which of the exceptions in `exception.InnerExceptions`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You still have the list of `Tasks`, and each `Task` has an `Exception` property. Using that you can figure out which exceptions belong with which `Task`.

But, if you can, it'd be better to use `Task.WhenAll` or `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll` than do a blocking Wait.

Comment: Isn't each [Task.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) pointing to the same `AggregateException exception` passed to `catch`?

Comment: No, each `Task` is unaware of the other tasks, and it will only have its own exception(s).

Comment: I have a good reason to wait on all. But I guess that that information is good for others. It's a bit wierd though that the exception by itself can't identify which task failed as it can be a child task that originally failed.

Comment: @jgauffin, many times you can use `await WhenAll` instead of `WaitAll`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var throwers = tasks.Where(task => task.Exception != null);
```

Comment: A few tasks may have thrown there, and their exceptions are aggregated into a single `AggregateException`, AFAIK

Comment: @Noseratio `throwers` above is a sequence of all the tasks which *did* throw an exception. Could be all, could be none, or could be any number inbetween - but they each have their own exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Task 1"));
        var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Task 2"));
        var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); });
        var t4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Task 4"));

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { t1, t2, t3, t4 }, tasks =>
            {
                foreach (var t in tasks)
                {
                    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                    {
                        // this will run for t3
                        Console.WriteLine("This task has been faulted.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Option1 (credit to @theodor-zoulias comment):

You can set the `Exception.Data` property with the task name:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.Data["task"] = "task1";
        throw exception;
    }
});

var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.Data["task"] = "task2";
        throw exception;
    }
});

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception was thrown by {exception.Data["task"]}");
    }
}
```

Option2:

If you don't mind loosing the name of the exception's assembly information, You can set the `Exception.Source` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.source?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)) property of the thrown exception based on the task name and look at it while iterating:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    throw new Exception() { Source = "t1" };
});
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    throw new Exception() { Source = "t2" };
});

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var exception in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception was thrown by {exception.Source}");
    }
}
```

Will output:

> Exception was thrown by t1
>
> Exception was thrown by t2

Comment: The [`Exception.Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.source#remarks) property is intended for providing information about the assembly in which the exception originated. You are losing information by hijacking this property. For user-defined info it's better to use the [`Exception.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data) property.

Comment: The `Data` is an `IDictionary`, so I don't think that your updated code compiles.